# Why isn't my localStorage.setItem() and localStorage.getItem() storing a value?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I want to store a user input value using localStorage then use that value in my countdown timer.

Here is the HTML where the user inputs their data:

```
<form action='/' method= 'GET' id='settings'>
                    <label> Work Time </label>
                    <input class='settingInput' type='number' id='workInput'> 

                    <label id='short-break'> Short Break </label>
                    <input class='settingInput' id='shortBreak'> 

                    <label id='long-break'> Long Break </label>
                    <input class='settingInput' id='longBreak'>

                    <button id = 'set-values'>Submit</button>
                </form>
```

this is the javascript to store and retrieve the data:

```
var workInputValue     = document.getElementById('workInput').value;
var workTimeSerialized = JSON.stringify(document.getElementById('workInput').value);
var workTimeFinal      = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('workTimeKey'));

submitButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    localStorage.setItem('workTimeKey', workTimeSerialized);
    console.log('submit pressed');
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

Here is the codepen for the whole project: https://codepen.io/Games247/pen/XWJqebG

This is my first time using setItem and getItem so I may be overlooking something obvious.

Currently it looks like a pair of brackets is stored in the localStorage where workTimeKey should be.

Comment: you should read the input values inside clickHandler

Answer (score 1):

Your linked code on codepen has a problem, in fact the code posted here corrects said problem.

```
var workTimeSerialized = JSON.stringify(document.getElementById('workInput'));
```

The above is your codepen, the problem is you are trying to serialize the HTML element to JSON rather than it's value hence the '{}' you see in your session storage.

You need to ensure it's the value of the input element and not the element itself you serialize. Like i mentioned, your code posted here resolves the issue ;

```
var workTimeSerialized = JSON.stringify(document.getElementById('workInput').value);
```

Note: Whenever you see '[]' or '{}' in session storage rather than your intended value, you are either passing an object directly or an element in your case.

**Edit:**
'you are **most likely** not either'

Your input values should be read in the submit click handler otherwise, you get the value of the input before sumbit and not after

So your code:

```
var workInputValue     = document.getElementById('workInput').value;
var workTimeSerialized = JSON.stringify(document.getElementById('workInput').value);
var workTimeFinal      = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('workTimeKey'));

submitButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    localStorage.setItem('workTimeKey', workTimeSerialized);
    console.log('submit pressed');
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

becomes:

```
submitButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
var workInputValue     = document.getElementById('workInput').value;
var workTimeSerialized = JSON.stringify(document.getElementById('workInput').value);
var workTimeFinal      = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('workTimeKey'));
    localStorage.setItem('workTimeKey', workTimeSerialized);
    console.log('submit pressed');
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: After the fix the key has a value of "".

Comment: @games247 I've edited the answer to explain what is happening and how you might fix it.